# Starting a service only after another one is completely started (on CentOS)

Tags: centos, init.d, centos6.2, startup-scripts

I have installed on my `CentOS` server `postgresql` service and another one called `netnfork`. The 'netnfork' service starts only after `postgresql` starts.

`netnfork` init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# netnfork init
#
# chkconfig: 2345 99 15
# description: netnfork
...
```

From `netnfork`'s init script you can see that start order is 99.

The `postgresql` init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# postgresql    This is the init script for starting up the PostgreSQL
#               server.
#
# chkconfig: - 64 36
# description: PostgreSQL database server.
...
```

As you can see from the `postgresql`'s init script, the start order is 64. **The problem is that there are some times when the `netnfork` service fails to start due to the fact that `postgresql` service isn't completely started. I know that from log files**.

Do you have any workaround for that issue?

---

N.B. I also put on `netnfork`'s init script the following line:

`# Required-Start: network postgresql-9.1`,

but without any results.

Comment: In a pinch, I'd just manage both daemons with [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). But that's not a clean fix.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your startup service is named `postgresql` not `postgresql-9.1`

Try this out in `netnfork`:

```
# Required-Start: network postgresql
```